# For oracle function to know if data is prime or not. Getting Warning: Function created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql

Wanted to create a function that can return records containing the number data type which are prime number
But getting warning of compilation error. What is the mistake in the code.I am a beginner in pl/sql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isPrime (num number)
RETURN number
IS
retVal number;
BEGIN
DECLARE
prime_or_notPrime number;
counter number;
    retVal:= 1;
    prime_or_notPrime:= 1
    counter:= 2
    WHILE (counter <= num/2)  LOOP
        IF (mod(num ,counter)= 0)  THEN
            prime_or_notPrime: = 0
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        IF (prime_or_notPrime = 1 ) THEN
            retVal: = 1;
        counter: = counter + 1
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    return retVal;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the mistake in the code

- The `DECLARE` is invalid syntax for a function/procedure. You want to declare the variables between the `IS` and `BEGIN` keywords.
- Then you are missing a `;` statement terminator after `prime_or_notPrime:= 1` and `counter:= 2`.
- Then you have:

  - `prime_or_notPrime: = 0` instead of `prime_or_notPrime := 0;`
  - `retVal: = 1;` instead of `retVal := 1;` and
  - `counter: = counter + 1` instead of `counter := counter + 1;` (they all have a space between `:` and `=` and some are missing `;` again).
- You never set `retVal` to anything other than 1.
- You do not handle `NULL` values or values lower than 2.

Fixing that (and the indentation) gives:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isPrime (num number)
RETURN number
IS
  retVal number;
  prime_or_notPrime number;
  counter number;
BEGIN
  IF NUM IS NULL OR NUM < 2 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;

  retVal:= 1;
  prime_or_notPrime:= 1;
  counter:= 2;
  WHILE (counter <= num/2)  LOOP
    IF (mod(num ,counter)= 0)  THEN
      prime_or_notPrime := 0;
      retVal := 0;
      EXIT;
    END IF;
    IF (prime_or_notPrime = 1 ) THEN
      counter := counter + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  return retVal;
END;
/
```

Note: the `prime_or_notprime` variable is not controlling anything as, as soon as you set it to `0` you `EXIT` from the loop so it will never be used again. Having noted that, you can get rid of the final `IF` statement and just always increment the counter.

---

You can simplify it to:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isPrime (
  num number
) RETURN number DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF NUM IS NULL OR NUM < 2 THEN
    RETURN 0;
  END IF;

  FOR counter IN 2 .. SQRT(num)  LOOP
    IF MOD(num, counter) = 0  THEN
      RETURN 0;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN 1;
END;
/
```

You can then consider improvements. Such as starting by checking `2` as a special case and then skipping all the other even numbers.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f8e4ccd99cce822b188ec15aad0e75bc)*

Comment: ... then, more improvements: check 3 and then skip all multiples of 3, etc. The sieve of Eratosthenes is one of the problems where the top contributors to the Oracle discussion board couldn't find a good pure-SQL solution; it's quite easily implemented in PL/SQL. https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3931268/sql-puzzle-prime-numbers/p1